# Why doesn't LINQ's First method simply return null if no item is found?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I don't really understand the purpose of [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) versus [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx). I mean, I understand the functional difference. But I don't really "get" why Microsoft thought there should be two different methods for this? Does anyone know?

Comment: First guarantee you'll have a result FirstOrDefault doesn't. First throws an exception when there are no results, FirstOrDefault ends normally and the result is null

Comment: It gives you the chance to know whether or not something was in the collection.  You don't necessarily know whether the default from `FirstOrDefault` was actually in the collection or not.

Comment: @Mystra007 Good point, I was a bit too hasty with my first comment: `new string[] { null, "Hello world" }` shows a reason for the difference.

Comment: There's a *semantic* difference here: `FirstOrDefault` says *"give me the first item if there is one"*. `First` says: *"I **know** the sequence is **not** empty. Give me the first item."*

Comment: its kind of like having simple convert vs tryparse, instead of handling exception manually in case of First why not FirstOrDefault?

Comment: The point of First() is you use it where you know that there should be at least one item and if there is not then it is a bug and should throw, if this case is not exceptional then use FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Not sure this should be put on hold, consider the (non-opinion-based?) following: Sometimes you want an exception being thrown in order to expose a critical error in your data. It also states to developers working on the code that not found should be unhandled. Contrast that with checks for `if(..OrDefault() != null)` all over the code. When working on this code, you have no idea if the application is supposed to work and keep chugging along when the value is null, or if it really shouldn't. Plus, it keeps null from being a magic value, too.

Comment: Yea, ultimately I guess it's no different than using `Convert.ToXyzType()` versus `XyzType.TryParse()` or something along those lines. The particular methods in question just really caught me off guard when I just encountered this exception while testing and I had no idea how to handle it, until I saw the remark about `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Similarly I don't understand why microsoft thought of two different methods convert.Tostring() and .toString(), If Convert.ToString() can handle null values then why there is need of .ToString() ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` provides **two** logical paths to handle whether there is a data result or there is not. Hence its handling is only *local to the scope* which it is called in. `First` provides a method to jump out of the local scope via an exception.

**Design WHY**

`First` only returns data for the current scope but gives the ability to handle any *unusual* or *unforseen* circumstance of no data and will handle that as an application *type* error via an `Exception`. That exception can be handled by a centralized controller outside of the current scope.

Hence it depends on how one wants to handle the lack of data and whether to handle it locally or outside of the local scope and to what degree the no data situation should be processed.

> why Microsoft thought there should be two different methods for this?

Flexibility for the programmer to code for different situations as needs dictate.

Comment: I really like usr's answer, but this I think I like this answer more-- perhaps because it directly pertains to what happened to me. I was checking `if (obj.First(i => i.val == Val) != null) ... else ...` and it blew up. I rearranged the code and threw assigned the `First()` result to a variable and saw it was `null`, so I was really confused why `null != null` was throwing this exception. Wasn't until I saw the `FirstOrDefault` remark on MSDN did I realize...

Answer (score 9):

`First` throws an exception if the sequence is empty. This is the only difference.

`First` has a built-in assertion that the sequence is not empty. That is it's purpose. Sometimes you know that the sequence cannot be empty. For example if you look up a customer in database A and it exists you know it will exist in database B as well. If it ever does not exist in B this would be a bug.

In case of a bug you want a loud bang to alert you of that. That's why assertions are often useful in production code. You certainly do *not* want to carry on executing with bad data. This makes finding the origin of bug harder, or might even hide the bug completely.

The whole point of `First` is that it is often super useful to have this built-in assertion.

The same is true for `Single` and `SingleOrDefault`. These assert that the sequence can never have more than one element. It turns out that this is often what you want in real-world code.

`FirstOrDefault` also allows you to handle the case where the sequence is empty whereas `First` does not (catching the exception would be a misuse of exceptions).

Also, `First` documents your knowledge about the sequence length so that this fact is obvious to anyone who reads the code.

Comment: I especially like the last part you wrote.

Comment: You could have also talked about the versions of these methods that take a predicate. `First` and `FirstOrDefault` return as soon as the first matching item in a sequence is found. They'll throw (or return default) if none match. `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` must iterate over the entire sequence to validate that there is only one matching item. They'll throw (or return default) if none match OR as soon as more than one match.

Comment: @CoderDennis How is that at all relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: @Servy I was just trying to point out that `Single` doesn't always assert that the sequence can never have more than one element as stated in this answer. It does that if you ignore the version of `Single` with a predicate. It's not really related to the question, which is why I only added it as a comment.

Comment: I agree with Magnus, I particularly like your last bit there, @usr. I generally prefer the most explicit, "strict" usage of things. Definitely a good point that, knowing the difference between the two, using `First()` should clearly convey that there is SUPPOSED to be data and the exception is indicative of a bigger problem.